# IOS6 FB sdk startForMeWithCompletionHandler how to set the result as function return variable

Tags: facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to get simple current user info and return it as parameter from the function . From reading I understand that I need to use the startForMeWithCompletionHandler method. Great.

After I authenticate with Facebook, I try to invoke the API by calling the   startForMeWithCompletionHandler method. However, the block executed but its never returned as the method return parameter . Why?

This is the method that I am calling:

```
-(id<FBGraphUser>) getLoggedInUserdata
{
    __block id<FBGraphUser> userInfo;
    if(FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
    {
        NSLog(@"Session is open");
    }

    [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id<FBGraphUser> userInfoResult, NSError *error) {
        if(FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
        {
            if(!error)
            {
                userInfo = userInfoResult;
            }
        }
    }];

    return userInfo;
}
```

from MainViewController :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.title = @"Facebook Sample app";
    httpClient = [[FBCHttpClient alloc] init];

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if(FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
    {
        id<FBGraphUser> fbGraphUser = httpClient.getLoggedInUserdata;
        NSLog(@"%@",[fbGraphUser name]);
    }

}
```

I call it after I successfully authenticate against Facebook and FBSession.activeSession.isOpen is true.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The startForMeWithCompletionHandler method is asynchronous, so it will be called whenever you call it, but it will not execute until your code is done with its execution first.